# The intersection of subgroups is normal?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $B$ a (infinite) subgroup of $G$. For each $a$ in $G$ denote by $H_a = \left<a,B \right>$. Consider $M_a = \left<a^{H_a} \right>$. Then  $M = \displaystyle \bigcap_{a \in G} M_a$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: What is the notation $\left<a^{H_a} \right>$ means?

Comment: $\left<a^{H_a}\right>$ is the subgroup generated by $a^{H_a}$ and the elements of $a^{H_a}$ has the form $a^x = x^{-1}ax$ where $x \in H_a$. Now is ok @Krish?

Comment: Have you tried it for a relatively familiar group? Like $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: I am sure the answer is no. Why would imagine that it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, I would suggest $G = {\rm Alt}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ countably infinite, and $B$ the stabilizer of $1$. Note that $G$ and $B$ are isomorphic and simple. Then $M_a = B$ if $a \in B$ and $M_a=G$ if $a \not\in B$, so $M=B$ is not normal in $G$.